# Python Sqlite query help needed?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to get data from my security and exchange tables. The columns in exchange are id, mic, exchange_code, and security tables have id, country, ticker, full_name, exchange_id. I want columns from both tables (like `id, ticker, full_name, country, mic, exchange_code` ).  I have tried this query in SQLite it's working fine in the SQLite browser.

```
SELECT security.id, ticker, security.country, exchange_code AS exchange, mic from security
INNER JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = security.exchange_id;
```

But when I tried in VS Code it shows empty dataset. The query is:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT security.id, ticker, security.country, exchange_code AS exchange, mic from security
    INNER JOIN exchange ON exchange.id = exchange_id
    GROUP BY security.id ORDER BY ticker
""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem to miss

```
ON exchange.id = security.exchange_id;
```

and not

```
exchange.id = exchange_id
```

`exchange_id` doesn't exist, this is why you have an empty result

Comment: can you mark question as solved and answer usefull please ? :)

Comment: what is the reason same query was retrieving data on SQLite browser but not in VS code?